# PHPExcel read dropdown list current selected option

Tags: php, excel, list, phpexcel, dropdown

i have a problem reading a special "field" from an excel file using PHPExcel library, is a dropdown list like a html select floating between many cells and isn't associated to any specific cell.

The dropdown options are fetch from another sheet in the same document.
I need to open the file and read the necessary cells (already done) and get the selected option/value from each dropdown.

[image]

I tried everything, one last thing was read the file using phpexcel and write it again to a new file using phpexcel file writer, and these fields are missing, gone from the new document.

Any ideas? is this possible to do using these libraries?

Comment: Form elements are not supported by PHPExcel

Comment: but @MarkBaker will add it in for you for a small fee ;-)

Comment: @nogad - Too awkward, and I've resisted the temptation to add them, because form elements are largely useless without the VBA to support them... and proper VBA support is a major piece of work